# encoding with open parameter vs encode string method byte size

Tags: python, file, character-encoding

I have come across something that I can't get my head around.

So I try to encode my string with one unicode character using both string encode method and open encoding parameter. For some reason, there is a difference regarding written byte size between these two methods.

Here is sample code:

```
with open("in.txt", "wb") as f:
    no = f.write("Wlazł".encode("utf-8"))
    print(no) # -> 6
```

```
with open("in.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    no = f.write("Wlazł")
    print(no) # -> 5
```

Does anyone know why this is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a file in binary mode you get an instance of [io.RawIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase), and [RawIOBase.write](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.write) returns the number of *bytes* written.

When you open a file in text mode you get an instance of [io.TextIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase), and [TextIOBase.write](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) returns the number of *characters* written.

So the reason for the difference is that one is a count of *bytes*, the other of *characters*.